# How does this restore Kurn, Worf's brother's, honor?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, klingon, worf

DS9 "Sons of Mogh":

> KURN: I have never understood you, Worf. But I do know this. In your
> own way you are an honourable man.  (Kurn passes out.)
>
> WORF: **And you will be an honourable man again**, but not as my brother.

Then right after:

> WORF: What will he remember?
>
> BASHIR: He'll know he's a Klingon, and how to speak the language, and
> virtually everything he needs to know in order to survive, except **who
> he is.** And that's the first question he'll ask. Who am I? Do you have
> an answer?
>
> WORF: There is a man named Noggra, a friend of our father's. He will
> be arriving in a few hours. **He has agreed to provide Kurn with a new
> identity and a new family**. He will supply Kurn with all the answers he
> needs.
>
> BASHIR: Are you absolutely certain about this, Worf? Once I've erase
> his memory engrams it'll be almost impossible to restore them. He
> won't remember you or anything about his *real life*.
>
> WORF: It is the only way. You may begin.

Kurn's lineage is still the house of Mogh, a dishonored house. Kurn's "soul" is still the same. He wanted Worf to kill him to regain his honor so his soul would go to Stovokor (Klingon Heaven).

Erasing Kurn's memory, changing some DNA, doing plastic surgery, and changing where he lives hardly seems to change the main issues that caused his dishonor. His lineage is still the same. If simply adoption into a new house was a legal way to regain honor, they could have done this with Kurn's consent.

How does this restore Kurn's honor?

Comment: Presumably, Kurn's new persona is considered a new person, a blank slate. Merely making this transition doesn't restore his honor, but gives him a platform from which to establish it anew.

Comment: Perhaps honor can't be restored by being adopted into a new house, but if everyone thinks he is part of the bloodline of the new house, he will have his honor back--and as an honorable Klingon he wouldn't be willing to consciously lie about his bloodline, making the memory change necessary?

Comment: I think asking about Kurn's soul in your series of questions about this topic is confusing the issue. We have no idea how souls work or if they even exist (in real life or in Star Trek).

Comment: @ellesedil between tng, ds9 and voyager,  er have enough info to say Klingons have a solid understanding on how their souls work or how they expect/believe it to work. Heck,  remember spock put his soul in Bones?

Comment: @Politank-Z so his lineage, Klingon law, etc. don't matter? Isn't that all that really matters to Klingons(except maybe Worf)?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Why would you say "If everyone thinks he is part of the bloodline of the new house, he will have his honor back?" What is your basis for this?

Comment: @JMFB I am not aware of the relevant laws, temporal or spiritual, ever having been spelled out for us. We know Worf is fairly conservative about such things, and Worf & Dax are both quite knowledgeable about them. Neither of them raised an objection on those grounds. With only those inputs to work from, I can only speculate that there was some wiggle room to work with.

Comment: @Ellesedil It is irrelevant what our definition or understanding of souls are. The fact that they have their definition, law, etc. is relevant. Honor is important above all else to Klingons. There are defined rules about how gains or loses honor. Kurn's status is a legal one and it affects his soul according to Klingon custom. I am only asking about Klingon customs, laws, and definitions.

Comment: @Politank-Z  But aren't you thinking like a westernized human? Worf was unwilling to kill his brother again because he said he was viewing it like a human. In almost every episode that there are other Klingons around they almost always disapprove of Worf's behavior. Remember when Worf didn't enact vengeance in the hall? I'm not sure trusting Dax or Worf who both can't stomach many Klingon rituals is a good source. I'd like to figure out the wiggle room that's why I asked the question...

Comment: @JMFB I am a westernized human. Incidentally, the writers are exclusively human and mostly if not all westernized. Without better sources (and I'd love if anyone turned some up), there are two alternatives: the inconsistencies are due to something which we don't know and weren't pivotal to the story, or there was a hiccup in the writers' psychic connection to the actual Star Trek universe. I can speculate to the former, I find pursuit of the latter to be useless.

Comment: @Politank-Z you missed what I was saying. You were using Worf as a source for honor being restored in this manner. I am saying that it's just that he couldn't stomach killing his brother again (just like I and you I hope wouldn't). But this is a Klingon matter, Worf admits he cannot do what needs to be done in the episode. I'm wondering if his honor is just not restored, but it simply makes things more palatable for everyone. That still begs the question of his honor.

Comment: @JMFB - It was just a speculation, that's why I put it in a comment rather than as an answer. But the core of my speculation was just that in Klingon society family dishonor was based on bloodlines, so adoption wouldn't change one's honor as long as the biological parentage was known. If that's correct, then it would follow logically that the only way to restore Kurn's honor in the eyes of other Klingons would be to make everyone believe his bloodline was that of a house that had not been dishonored.

Comment: @Hypnosifl so you're saying that through trickery his honor could be restored. Hmm...seems dishonorable, lol. But again I am thinking like a human instead of a Klingon. Let's say it was found out, then what?

Comment: Hmm, is your question not about why they would need to do this to restore his honor in the eyes of Klingon society, but just about whether the Klingon belief system says his soul would still be dishonored even if no one except Worf, not even Kurn himself, knew about it? If so, perhaps we can infer from this episode that Worf wasn't really a true believer.

Comment: @Hypnosifl that's interesting. It's kind of always a struggle for Worf whether to believe or not. He's kind of searching. But he was willing to kill his brother at the beginning of the episode, that would take a considerable amount of belief, me thinks. Or...he was just doing it because he felt guilty about what he had done to Kurn in which case Kurns honor wasn't restored, but since Worf didn't really believe in all that stuff it doesn't matter.

Comment: @JMFB He might have been willing to kill his brother as a mercy, since for most Klingons a life without honor is probably seen as worth than death (though I guess it wasn't for Worf, perhaps because of his divided sense of identity). For a scene of Worf seemingly taking a sort of ambiguous position on religious belief, see [this youtube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATVG3cul1mw).

Comment: @JMFB Honor is an abstract. The perception of honor matters for dealings among Klingons; from that point of view, as  Rodek, he was an unknown, free to establish his honor afresh. In the EU, he manages to do so: http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Rodek The only other way the restoration of his honor has concrete value is if Sto-vo-kor and its admission requirements are reality. Given how unusual the circumstances are, I suspect that would be a judgement call.

Answer (score 5):

Who said this was legal in the society? He will have a new untarnished identity and no one but a few people will know the truth. Everyone else will think he's a random Klingon from a standard honorable house. Not counting actual Klingon afterlife, this will be the same as being honorable. And since Klingons can go from being dishonorable to honorable through their actions, even actual Klingon afterlife can consider him honorable in the future.

Honor in Klingon is as subjective as any status in real life. You are only as rich/well-mannered/famous/good/important as others think you are. If no one thinks you are an honorable Klingon, even if you really are, you are not honorable. How mortal Klingon society is involved, honor is subject to group consensus. We see plenty of Klingons on screen who are not honorable, but in universe they are still considered honorable until proven otherwise.

Comment: Kurn's main reason for coming to Worf was to regain his honor and go to Stovokor. His and Klingon's belief is that you have to have honor to go to Stovokor. Worf killing Kurn would be an honorable death and therefore Kurn would end up in Stovokor. The legalities of Klingon society govern what is honorable. What you're suggesting is that this is more convenient for everyone involved, but that doesn't change his status or the status of his soul, right?

Comment: If man made laws affect the soul,  no.  But if we consider honor to be as meaningless and subjective as "criminal" or "knighthood" or "freedom fighter/terrorist" or "good king/tyrant".

Comment: If you commit a crime,  and you don't know you did, and Noone else knows you did, are you a criminal?

Comment: We are speaking only of Klingon customs right now. Even Worf believes in them enough to try and kill Kurn. It only matters if under Klingon law his honor is restored. I'm not sure this does it. Maybe it does, but I'm confused about the mechanism.

Comment: Ha Ha, we are all criminals then. We all break the law. Ever drive over the speed limit? LOL. In any event we can debate these sort of philosophical ism's all day. Can god make a rock that god can't lift?

Comment: What if Kurn had gone into battle while his family's honor was at dishonorable status, but Kurn went into battle and died as a warrior. In that case he'd have an honorable death. Would he achieve Stovokor then? Would the Klingons consider his honor restored even though the family status is not?

Comment: That's a whole nother question. How much does family honor override personal honor?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that was not answered in the show because it wasn't the point of that episode.  The point was that Kurn, who had helped bring Gowron to power, was sick of being dishonored because of his brother's acceptance of discommendation in TNG "Sins of the Father".  In that episode, it is revealed upon examining data having come from a Romulan vessel, that Mogh did not send out the coded message.  It was, in fact, Ja'rod, father of Duras.  Mogh was used as a scapegoat, as Duras' family was too powerful and it would cause a civil war within the Empire.  The thought behind Kurn having his  mind erased and given a new family was that he could reclaim his honor in another way, and to show that sometimes there is no "good" or "easy" way to go about things, and that those actions also have consequences,  but, the reason as to how and why this can be done is a matter of a lot of debate, I would Imagine.

There is not a lot on exactly HOW the honor system works, other than what we've seen in the shows so far, but we can come up with a few conclusions based on what we do know.  In the DS9 episode "Homefront" we are given some info concerning Klingon Gods.

> "Our gods are dead. Ancient Klingon warriors slew them a millennia ago. They were... more trouble than they were worth."

In most religions, one's soul (although their own) typically belongs to that of whoever/whatever is believed to be the God/Gods of the religion.  Since the Klingons killed their gods, it can be concluded that Stovokor and Gre'thor are places like Heaven and Hell, places which cannot be proven by hard evidence as to exist or not.  Since the gods are dead, these places may still be part of the Klingon psyche and used to further iterate the importance of honor.  It was insinuated in the VOY episode "Barge of the Dead" that B'Elanna did go to Gre'thor, but even then, her mother was saved not by using rituals, but by B'Elanna being true to herself and living a good life, which would further denote that the honor system is subjective and based more on personal and societal norms for their culture, which may also mean that by Kurn being "made" into this different person, that he no longer carries the burden of dishonor that Worf has to, as he no longer has the knowledge of who Worf or Mogh are and, from his perspective, is not part of their family.  Not having to carry the burden any longer means that Kurn would not consider himself dishonored, and since the term is subjective, he would have no reason to suspect that he would end up in Gre'thor, and therefore would not go there upon his death.

In closing, it's been established that there are no Klingon gods anymore, and as such, conceivable that whatever power the gods had over their souls now belongs to them.  The honor system and the way in which they treat honor also does reveal that depending on the circumstances, it is a subjective and fluidic concept, and more dependent on the person and society than anything else.  Kurn's soul therefore would be intact because he has no knowledge and does not carry the burden he once did.  He had been given a new name and a new family, one who's reputation was not tarnished, so per the lore established, it can be concluded that his soul would be clean.  In TNG "Sins of the Father", it is established that the dishonor would carry down 7 generations, but this would most likely be more due to the fact that the family would be made to remember, as it would be noted by the High Counsel and the burden on the Family's souls would be made to be carried by the family members.

Side note:  Although in terms of lore, this answer works, it's also probably just due to the writing staff thinking more along the lines of "well if they do this, Kurn won't have to live with the dishonor" and had not even thought of how it would play into going to Stovokor or Gre'thor.

Comment: The first paragraph premise is incorrect.   Kurn's dishonor in DS9 was due to Gowron lashing out at Worf's house for refusing to participate in the invasion of Cardassia.